# How to also ignore warnings in pytest about removal in Django41?

Tags: python, django, pytest

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning teaches me to use this in my pytest.ini

`filterwarnings = ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning`

but i still get warnings that are like this:

```
../usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91: RemovedInDjango41Warning: 'pattern_library' defines default_app_config = 'pattern_library.apps.PatternLibraryAppConfig'. Django now detects this configuration automatically. You can remove default_app_config.
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
```

I would like to suppress this as well, as this is also a third party library of which I have no control over even though i have laready submitted a PR to update it.

What should i add to my pytest.ini?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register filters on the full import path for a given warning class; here that's `django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango41Warning`:

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
    ignore:.*Django now detects this configuration.*:django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango41Warning
```

Depending on your Django release, `RemovedInDjango41Warning` is a subclass of either [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning) (Django 4.0, still in development) or of [`PendingDeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PendingDeprecationWarning) (Django 3.2), and that warning filters are matched by subclass as well, so:

```
ignore:.*Django now detects this configuration.*:PendingDeprecationWarning
ignore:.*Django now detects this configuration.*:DeprecationWarning
```

will work too, for both Django 3.2 and 4.0.